Migration of UI test cases of a desktop application to Azure virtual machine scale set from Azure virtual machine
I am trying to migrate UI test cases of a desktop application to Azure virtual machine scale set. I am using C# and Winapp driver to automate UI testcases on a desktop application. When I am running UI test cases on a remote server through Azure deveops pipelines, I'm facing this error:
Test method UserInterface.Test.UIAndConsoleTestCases.VerifyAllNames threw exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to locate opened application window with appId: C:\Program Files\abc.exe, and processId: 5112
Stack Trace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities appiumOptions)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities appiumOptions, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsDriver`1..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, AppiumOptions AppiumOptions, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at UserInterface.Test.CommonData.CreateNewSession(String InstalledPath) in D:\a\1\s\Projects\UITestcasesWinApp\UserInterface.Test\Helper\CommonData.cs:line 63
at UserInterface.Test.UIAndConsoleTestCases.VerifyAllFieldNamesAndTypes() in D:\a\1\s\Projects\UITestcasesWinApp\UserInterface.Test\UIAndConsoleTestCases.cs:line 267
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
Standard Output Messages:
WinAppDriver started successfully!
Process ID: 432
Error: WaitForInputIdle failed. This could be because the process does not have a graphical interface.
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Error

I am running single job to test, in which there are several testcases. GRVU exe has several process Id, while its running, I got to know about this from the error log.

Note this message: Error: WaitForInputIdle failed. This could be because the process does not have a graphical interface.. Looks like you are running your test in command-line interface mode, not in GUI mode.

how can I check for, if I'm running in command-line interface mode or graphical interface mode?

Catch exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException upon start of your test.
